# Expression Engine conditional statements not behaving as expected

Tags: playa

I'm really very new with expression engine, so bear with me:

I have an exp:playa:parents call, and I need to set the category conditionally.

I have the following:

```
            {exp:playa:parents
                    {if segment_4 == "new_arrivals"}
                        {if segment_3 == "furniture"}
                            category="57"
                        {/if}
                        {if segment_3 == "lighting"}
                            category="59"
                        {/if}
                        {if segment_3 == "accents"}
                        category="58"
                        {/if}
                    {if:else}
                        category="{segment_4_category_id}"
                    {/if}
                    channel="products"
                    disable="categories|member_data"
                    dynamic="no"
                    limit="24"
                    paginate="bottom"
                    {if rev_segment_1 == "all"}limit="500"{/if}
            }
```

As a programmer, the if/else logic seems... logical, but that doesn't seem to help the fact that the category doesn't seem to get set properly at all.

Is there a subtlety to conditional statements in EE that I am clearly not understanding?  Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Any help would be so appreciated.

Edit:
the url that's failing: http://localhost/arcade/by/accents/new_arrivals

this page gets called in two places, and either that page output doesn't work (like it does with that else block in there) or the category doesn't get set properly here: http://localhost/damien_langlois_meurinne_for_pouenat/by/furniture/seating and it displays all the category types (not just seating) [this happens after removing the else block].

I've checked with the html comment method you mentioned, and all the data seems to be fine.

When I turn on the profiling output, I get this as well for the playa call:

```
 (0.122617 / 14.88MB) Tag: {exp:playa:parents entry_id="8380" {if segment_4 == "new_arrivals"} category="58" {if:else} category="57" {/if} channel="products" disable="categories|member_data" dynamic="no" limit="24" paginate="bottom" var_prefix="playavTWmYmQm"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't expect the conditionals to work inside a module call. I'd likely deal with the conditionals prior and come up with one variable and use that in the module call. You will have to use Stash from @croxton as it's handy in these situations.

This is not tested, just a thought:

```
{!-- We're inside an exp:channel call I expect --}
{exp:stash:set parse_conditionals="yes" trim="yes"}
<!-- Capture one stash to one variable -->
{stash:catID}
{if segment_4 == "new_arrivals"}
  {if segment_3 == "furniture"}57{/if}
  {if segment_3 == "lighting"}59{/if}
  {if segment_3 == "accents"}58{/if}
{if:else}{segment_4_category_id}{/if}
{/stash:catID}
<!-- Capture either 500 or 100 as the limit -->
{stash:limit}
  {if rev_segment_1 == "all"}"500"{if:else}"100"{/if}
{/stash:limit}
{/exp:stash:set}

<!-- May need to wrap this is in a parse tag to ensure the dreaded EE parse order rears its head -->
{exp:stash:parse}
  {exp:playa:parents
  category="{exp:stash:catID}"
  channel="products"
  disable="categories|member_data"
  dynamic="no"
  limit="24"
  paginate="bottom"
  limit={exp:stash:limit}
  parse="inward"
}
...
  {/exp:playa:parents}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

This is very crude but you can see the logic, capture your variables, set them and call them into the playa tag. There are a multitude of ways this can work and will require a bit of experimentation but the logic should be sound enough.

Comment: That worked perfectly!  I think I also gained an better understanding of how EE templating gets structured.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn’t appear to be anything wrong with the logic, though you could be more concise using the {if:elseif} construct perhaps.  Perhaps if you post the URL that is failing, and what you get from the logic statement for that URL, it might be easier to work out what is going on.

You might have thought of this already - but if not, sometimes it helps to simply dump out the variables as a comment in the HTML so you can see what actually is being used in the logic… so something like:

```
<!—- Segment 1: {segment_1} / Segment 2: {segment_2} … —>
```